# If error with batch : not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file

Whenever I run the batch file and get to confirming username, it throws an error:

```
'ifyes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ifyes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ifyes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ifyes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've searched and found no answer's, I read the MS documentation on batch and everything seems to be fine, please help.

Code:

```
@echo off

color 0f
title Console Setup

echo Console Setup Is Now Undergoing, please wait...
echo.

timeout /t 2 /nobreak

:back1

set /p username=Please Enter A Username - 

set /p answerUsername=Username chosen as %username%, are you sure? - 

if%answerUsername%=="yes" goto contin1
if%answerUsername%=="Yes" goto contin1
if%answerUsername%=="no" goto back1
if%answerUsername%=="No" goto back1

:contin1
set /p password=Please enter your password %username% - 

echo %password%

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a separator-space between the if-command and the condition.

Comment: @OP: You also need to quote both sides of the comparison operator as the match is literal, eg. `if "%answerUsername%"=="yes" goto contin1`. Also, if /i` will perform a case-sensitive comparison. And if the user input is `xyz` for example, your code will simply proceed through all of your `if` statements and execute the code after the label `:contin1`. Please search SO for `choice` or execute `choice /?` from the prompt for a better way to ask a Yes/No question.